# recycler adapter is not updating on calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: list, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I passed a list to the adapter from an activity and on calling *notifydatasetchanged*, *recycler view* is still empty, It is not updating the view.

```
    var list : ArrayList<StationBean> = ArrayList()
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.stations_adapter, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.stationsName.text = list.get(position).stationName
        holder.cityName.text = list.get(position).latitude.toString()
    }
    fun add_data(data : StationsListDataClass)
    {
           list = data.stationBeanList
           notifyDataSetChanged()
           Log.d("List", list.toString())
    }
}
```

////// .   Setting the adapter .

```
  private var adapter: StationsListAdapter = StationsListAdapter(this)
   recycler_view_stationsList.apply {

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            this.adapter = adapter
        }
```

///// Layout File

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_stationsList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

// .  Main Activity Full Code , I used inject for calling presenter,The main problem is in the setRecycler function

```
 @Inject
    lateinit var stationsListPresenter: StationsListPresenter
    private lateinit var station_adapter: StationsListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stations_list)
       setupRecycler()
        stationsListPresenter.downLoadStationsListUsingRetrofit()
    }

    private fun setupRecycler()
    {
        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_stations_list)
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@StationsListActivity) // replace MainActivity with your activity name
            station_adapter = StationsListAdapter(this@StationsListActivity)
        }

            recyclerView.adapter = station_adapter

    }


    override fun addNewsToRecyclerView(stationsList: StationsListDataClass)
    {
        station_adapter.add_data(stationsList)


    }
    override fun makeInjection(activityComponent: ActivityComponent) {

        activityComponent.inject(this)
    }
```

The View is still empty after calling notifydatasetchanged()
and I am not getting any error.
The List have around 800 objects.
Recycler View is showing null pointer exception, even after binding view using findviewbyID

Comment: Share your `activity code` where you` implement` the `recyclerview` and `adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your xml layout and/or setting up recycler view code. Maybe there is no LayoutManager set. You may set it in xml or in the activity/fragment:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

also try clearing your list in add_data()

```
list.clear()
list.addAll(..)
```

Comment: I cannot see the addNewsToRecyclerView called anywhere... Do you call it somewhere? Here, in above code, you never call the function and do you never populate the adapter with Your data...

Answer (score 0):

And modify your `add_data` function like this

```
fun add_data(data : StationsListDataClass){
     list.clear()
     list.addAll(data.stationBeanList)
     notifyDataSetChanged()
     Log.d("List", list.toString())
}
```

**Update**

Modify your `setupRecycler` like below

```
private fun setupRecycler(){
    var recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_stations_list)

    station_adapter = StationsListAdapter(this@StationsListActivity)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@StationsListActivity)

    recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView?.adapter = station_adapter
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error,
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

And it is pointing towards the recycler view object. 
I attached the view in the kotlin class like this,
val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_stations_list)
but still it shows null pointer exception

Comment: Please check the main activity